# Regexp for parse log with fluentd

Tags: regex, fluentd

I'm trying to parse application log with some regexp. I was able to parse the timestamp. But after that, If I try to add more expressions to the fluentd format the first attribute "time" disappears with giving me an exception. And no records are matched.

I'm using Fluentular.

Log message will be something like:

```
Date=[2018-04-11 08:44:30,219] Thread=[20] Level=[INFO] EventId=[2] Message=[Request finished in 1.1825ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8]
```

This is the first regexp with the first key (There is an issue with milliseconds but is not important). In the attributes I can see the key Time with this value.

[First regexp ok](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%29.%2B%3F%28%3F%3D%5C%5D%29%29&input=Date%3D%5B2018-04-11%2008%3A44%3A30%2C219%5D%20Thread%3D%5B20%5D%20Level%3D%5BINFO%5D%20EventId%3D%5B2%5D%20Message%3D%5BRequest%20finished%20in%201.1825ms%20200%20text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8%5D&time_format=%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S)

then If I try to isolate more info on the log I lose the first key and I'm unable to parse any other data.

[Regexp with second key](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%29.%2B%3F%28%3F%3D%5C%5D%29%29%20%28%3F%3Cmethod%3E%5B%5E%20%5D*%29&input=Date%3D%5B2018-04-11%2008%3A44%3A30%2C219%5D%20Thread%3D%5B20%5D%20Level%3D%5BINFO%5D%20EventId%3D%5B2%5D%20Message%3D%5BRequest%20finished%20in%201.1825ms%20200%20text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8%5D&time_format=%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S)

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE:

based on comments now I have this expression

```
(?<time>\[(?<time>[^\]\[]+)])\s+(?<Thread>\S+)\s+(?<Level>\S+)\s+(?<EventId>\S+)\s+(?<Message>[^ ].*$)
```

[Regexp 3](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%5C%5B%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%5B%5E%5C%5D%5C%5B%5D%2B%29%5D%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3CThread%3E%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3CLevel%3E%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3CEventId%3E%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3CMessage%3E%5B%5E%20%5D.*%24%29&input=Date%3D%5B2018-04-11%2008%3A44%3A30%2C219%5D%20Thread%3D%5B20%5D%20Level%3D%5BINFO%5D%20EventId%3D%5B2%5D%20Message%3D%5BRequest%20finished%20in%201.1825ms%20200%20text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8%5D&time_format=%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S)

Is almost perfect. The only problem is that, the expression also get the square bracket

Key   Thread
Value Thread=[20]

I don't know if this expression can be improved to avoid the

"Thread=[]"

UPDATE 2:

In order to do test, I installed fluentd via apt with the plugin and do some tests and my final setup is something like

```
<parse>
        @type kv
        time_key Date
        types Date:time:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,Thread:integer,Level:string,EventId:integer,Message:string
        kv_delimiter /\]\s+/
        kv_char "=["
```

Seems better now:

```
2018-04-11 08:44:30.219000000 +0200 kv_log: {"Thread":20,"Level":"INFO","EventId":2,"Message":"Request finished in 1.1825ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8]"}
```

Comment: What is expected with second regex?

Comment: You should  convert the lookarounds to consuming patterns, rely on capturing. E.g. `\[(?<time>[^\]\[]+)]\s+(?<method>\S+)`. Your pattern does not work because the `(?=\])` does not consume the `]` and you must put it after the capturing group anyway. What is your end goal here?

Comment: Basically, is to parse the different records of the log, get the data of the Date, Thread, Level, EventID and finally Message. So Splunk will get all the data parsed in different records or attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to parse the key-value pairs with the [Key-Value Pairs Parser Plugin for Fluentd](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-kv-parser).

**Parameters**

- `kv_delimiter /\]\s+(?=\w+=)/` (or just `/\]\s+/`) (see [how the kvp pairs are split here](https://regex101.com/r/8u2Cq3/1))
- `kv_char "=["` (the string will be used to split the key from the value)